# How to find one value depending on what we want to edit

Tags: reactjs

I have a problem when I want to edit the data, I want to pop up the value from different post request. for the example. When I edit one column where clientId = pocket so the value of urlblacklist will pop up where clientId = pocket, I mean when I want to select one value so all the value will appear where clientId = e.g pocket. In php select urlBlackList from tableA join tableB on tableA.clientId = tableB.clientId . ehhehe. That's what I mean.

here my code

detailclient.js

```
getPostAPI = () => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    const authorize = localStorage.getItem('tokenauthorize')
        axios.post(`http://10.50.51.21:8062/clients`, {} ,
      {
        headers:
          {
            "User-Agent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.90 Safari/537.36",
            "AUTHENTICATION-KEY" : token,  
            "AUTHORIZATION-KEY" : authorize
          }
      })
      .then((res)=>{
        let response = res;
        if(response){
            this.setState ({
              post : response.data.response
            })   
          }

      },this)
      .catch( (error) => {        
          alert('Error Mendapatkan Client',error)
        }
      )
  }

  getBlacklistToken = () => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    const authorize = localStorage.getItem('tokenauthorize')
        axios.put(`http://10.50.51.21:8062/blacklist/broadcast`, {} ,
      {
        headers:
          {
            "User-Agent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.90 Safari/537.36",
            "AUTHENTICATION-KEY" : token,  
            "AUTHORIZATION-KEY" : authorize
          }
      })
      .then((res)=>{
        let response = res;
        console.log(response.data.response)
        if(response){
            this.setState ({
              post2 : response.data.response
            })   
          }

      },this)
      .catch( (error) => {        
          alert('Error Mendapatkan Blacklist',error)
        }
      )
    }

    componentDidMount () {
      this.getPostAPI();
      this.getBlacklistToken();

  }
```

here the code i want to pop up

```
<FormGroup>
                            <Label htmlFor="urlBlacklist">Url Blacklist</Label>

                            {(this.state.post2.find(h => `${h.clientId}` === post.clientId) <Input onChange={this.handleForm} value = {h.urlBlacklist} key={h.clientId} type="text"  name = "urlBlacklist" className="form-control" placeholder="Url Blacklist" required="" />)}
                         </FormGroup>
```

please tell me if you need more code . thank you for help me

Comment: try {(this.state.post2.filter(h => h.clientId === post.clientId)&&
                               < Input onChange .../> )}

Comment: i already try still dont want to change, filter cant use on this case